# How to update the page when file was updated? (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a json file on my ftp Server that's called "Series.json".
My question is like how can I update my website without reloading the page when I upload my json file?

Comment: You're looking for ajax, Google it

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no real answer to this questions as there are a lot of different ways to achieve it.

Check jQuery documentation (assume you use it by looking at question's tags) for the `.ajax()` method. Ideally you would also build some backend service like `/getMySeriesJson?lastUpdate=<timestamp>`. If it has changed the server will return the file (contents). Otherwise the server could return nothing and set the HTTP status to 304 Not modified. Your frontend/consumer would then have to handle this responses accordingly.

Comment: I would go like setInterval(myFunction(), 10000) and I don't really know much about ajax/jquery.